# Launching Ionic app routing

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, deep-linking

Found this solution to lounching app via plugin

```
.run(['$state', '$window',
function($state, $window) {
    $window.addEventListener('LaunchUrl', function(event) {
        // gets page name from url
        var page =/.*:[/]{2}([^?]*)[?]?(.*)/.exec(event.detail.url)[1];
        // redirects to page specified in url
        $state.go('tab.'+ page, {});
    });
}]);

function handleOpenURL(url) {
setTimeout( function() {
    var event = new CustomEvent('LaunchUrl', {detail: {'url': url}});
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
}, 0);}
```

This solution works great if use simply state name, ex. myapp://posts

```
.state('app.posts', {
url: "/posts",
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: "templates/posts.html",
    controller: 'PostsCtrl'
  }
}})
```

open app/posts.

But I need open state like this

```
.state('app.post', {
url: "/posts/:postId",
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: "templates/post.html",
    controller: 'PostCtrl'
  }
}})
```

with link myapp://post/2525.
Can somebody help with this? Thank you!

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Well done! I suggest taking a look here: https://medium.com/angularjs-articles/deep-linking-in-ionic-mobile-applications-44d8b4685bb3#.aagcscthf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved myself )))

```
.run(['$state', '$window',
function($state, $window) {
    $window.addEventListener('LaunchUrl', function(event) {
        // gets page name from url
        var page =/.*:[/]{2}([^?]*)[?]?[/]{1}([^?]*)[?]?/.exec(event.detail.url)[1];
        var id =/.*:[/]{2}([^?]*)[?]?[/]{1}([^?]*)[?]?/.exec(event.detail.url)[2];
        // redirects to page specified in url
        // alert ("id:" +id);
        $state.go('app.'+ page, {'postId': + id});
    });
}]);
```